# How to find the last Logged-In time for the external user for a SharePoint online Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom, external-users

I need to know about the information for the external user last logged-in time over a site. Is it possible to get through REST or Client-Object Modal?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, and my hope is that I am incorrect and someone will come and prove me wrong. :)

Comment: You can find user login details and activity from Microsoft Compliance center.  Auditing feature must be enabled before using it. Further you can access these details from api using Microsoft graph.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what site they'll be using, you could turn on audit logging and check the last time they trigger a basic audit case like:

> Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties

This of course assumes that when people log in they then open or view an item (probably a page...), but I think that is a fair assumption.

You need to have this setup beforehand though (won't be able to go back and find people from before you turn auditing on).

Turn on audit logging under Site Collection Administration > Configure Audit Settings

When you want to know info about someone generate an audit report for that specific user and use some good old fashioned excel skills to sort the sheet by event time.

Comment: Even I Have also researched over this and found not recommended action for Sharepoint online . it can be performed efficiently and in a controlled manner  for Sharepoint On-Premises.